# How do I find the intercept of X , given three points $P(x,y,z) , Q(x,y,z) , R(x,y,z)$ in a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

I have three points in a plane, i need to find where it intercepts in the x axis , how do I find the coordinate that does that? I have to figure out the plane equation first?

Comment: Plane equation first, then let $y=z=0$.

Comment: The points on the plane are of the form $\lambda(Q-P)+\mu(R-P)+P$. Set the second and third coordinate to $0$ and solve for $\lambda,\mu$. If there is a uniqe solution, there is a unique solution, which is $\lambda(Q-P)+\mu(R-P)+P$. If there is not a unique solution, then the plane contains the x-axis.

Comment: Thanks tavish and levent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to figure out the plane equation.

Let $X(x_0,0,0)$ be the intersection point:

We have:

$$\begin{vmatrix}x_0&x_P&x_Q&x_R\\ 
0&y_P&y_Q&y_R\\ 
0&z_P&z_Q&z_R\\ 
1&1&1&1
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

Why that ? Because $\tfrac16$ of this determinant is equal to the volume of tetrahedron $PQRX$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3626329)) and we want this volume to be $0$.

It remains to expand this determinant with respect to the first column and solve for $x_0$:

$$x_0=\dfrac{\begin{vmatrix}x_P&x_Q&x_R\\ 
y_P&y_Q&y_R\\ 
z_P&z_Q&z_R\\ 
\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
y_P&y_Q&y_R\\ 
z_P&z_Q&z_R\\ 
1&1&1
\end{vmatrix}}$$

with the condition that the denominator is not zero, of course.

Comment: Thank you Jean Marie!